# Lambda writes to DynamoDb on Test Event but not when Triggered with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudfront

I want to save every request to my S3 object in DynamoDB.
[This is my pipeline.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGVIp.jpg)

I'm deploying the function to Lambda@Edge with **viewer-response** as the trigger and just to make sure that the function runs I'm also inserting a custom header with the image served. The header is coming as expected hence the function runs.

When I test this function via the Lambda Console, it is inserting the entry in DynamoDB. The problem is that while it's returning the custom header, it's not making a DB entry when I go to the CloudFront CDN URL.

For example when I goto https://d********e.cloudfront.net/test-image.png it should -

1. Serve the Respective Image (Working Properly)
2. Have the custom header (Working Properly)
3. Store entry in DynamoDB (Not working)

Here's the code for reference. Please note that the function is storing an entry in DB while running a test event in Lambda Console and I want this function to run every time the CDN serves an image.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const shortid = require('shortid');

module.exports.image = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;

    headers['mycustomheader'] = [{ key: 'My-Custom-Header', value: new Date().getTime().toString() }];

    await storeClickEvent(event);
    callback(null, response);
};

const storeClickEvent = async (data) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'my-dummy-table-name',
        Item: {
            event: data,
            id: shortid.generate(),
            createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
        }
    };

    try {
        await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error occurred =>', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a permissions issue, Can you see if the request makes it to the lambda (look in the lambdas monitoring/logs)?

Comment: It does not make it to the logs. But if the function wasn't running, then how is the custom header present in response?